# How To Fix This Bug java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, runtime, runtimeexception, lang

I'Am Face This Bug How To Fix It

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2941)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3088)
      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1815)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6846)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:504)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
      at com.deepthistudio.sinhalabehethapp.Logo_Screen.onCreate (Logo_Screen.java:19)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8606)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8597)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1274)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2919)
```

```
public class Logo_Screen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logo_screen_activity);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();


        Thread Thread = new Thread(() -> {

            try
            {
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Logo_Screen.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);

            }
        });
        Thread.start();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: On line `19` of your `Logo_Screen` class, a `NullPointerException` is being thrown. Fix this problem by making whatever is `null` _not_ `null`, or by otherwise properly handling the `null` reference.

Comment: By the way, `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` is an astoundingly bad thing to do. In this case you're pretty much only ever going to get an InterruptedException, but swallowing exceptions like that is going to burn you one day.

Comment: He! Bro I don't Understand This. Can you tell me how to fix it?